# Find the mode in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

The mode is the value that appears most often in a set.

I would like something like:

```
SELECT
    t.id as t_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.value) as value_list,
    MODE(t.value) AS value_mode
FROM dataset.table as t
GROUP BY t_id
```

such that, for example:

```
t_id    value_list     value_mode
1       2,2,2,3,6,6    2
```

How is that done?

**EDIT**:  The value_list is just there for illustration purpose.  Only need the mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, value as value_list, v as value_mode
from (
  select 
    id, value, v, 
    count(1) as c, 
    row_number() over(partition by id order by c desc) as top
  from (
    select id, value, split(value) as v 
    from dataset.table 
  )
  group by id, value, v
)
where top = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I often have to find the mode of prices for respective groups (e.g. length and amps) to filter out sale prices and the like. 
I typically use two methods both with creating an array and un-nesting it in order of frequency. One method I use is by a `LIMIT` another with an `[OFFSET(0)]` in case you want to get Nth values.

Both are included below:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 18 AS length, 
'HIGH' as amps, 
99.95 price UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "HIGH", 99.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "HIGH", 5.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "LOW", 33.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "LOW", 33.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "LOW", 4.5 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "HIGH", 77.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "HIGH", 77.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "HIGH", 9.99 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "LOW", 44.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "LOW", 44.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "LOW", 5.65 
)

SELECT
  length,
  amps,

  -- By Limit
  (SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1 ) most_freq_price,
  (SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC  LIMIT 1 ) least_freq_price,

  -- By Offset
  ARRAY((SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC))[OFFSET(0)] most_freq_price_offset,
  ARRAY((SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC))[OFFSET(0)] least_freq_price_offset

FROM (
  SELECT 
    length,
    amps,
    ARRAY_AGG(price) price_array
  FROM t
  GROUP BY 1,2
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a direct function available now

> approx_top_count()

Here is an example of its usage
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_top_count

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For your example, this is how I would solve it:

```
SELECT x, w mode
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) c, w, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) rn, FIRST(x) x
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(x) w, x FROM (SELECT "2,2,2,3,6,6" x)
  )
  GROUP BY 2
)
WHERE rn=1
```

And with the GROUP_CONCAT within query:

```
SELECT gc, w mode
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) c, w, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) rn, FIRST(gc) gc
  FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(w) OVER() gc, w
    FROM (FLATTEN((
      SELECT SPLIT(x) w, x FROM (SELECT "2,2,2,3,6,6" x)), w)
    )
  )
  GROUP BY 2
)
WHERE rn=1
```

And handling partitions:

```
SELECT tid, gc value_list, w value_mode
FROM (
  SELECT tid, COUNT(*) c, w, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tid ORDER BY c DESC) rn, FIRST(gc) gc
  FROM (
    SELECT tid, GROUP_CONCAT(w) OVER(PARTITION BY tid) gc, w
    FROM (FLATTEN((
      SELECT 1 tid, SPLIT(x) w, x FROM (SELECT "2,2,2,3,6,6" x)), w)
    )
  )
  GROUP BY tid, w
)
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: How would this work with GROUP BY t_id ? Do you need to add PARTITION BY to your query ?

Comment: I would have done that if the example in the question would have been more complex :). (My answers are way more specific when the questions include a table I can work with)